# When you fry fish or meat, does the interior fat stay inside or does it come out and the surface absorbs the cooking oil instead?

Tags: oil, fat

My question applies to both deep frying and sauteing.

With boiling, grilling or roasting, fat will come out of the meat.  So much of the fat or oils in meat or fish will leave the meat.

Does this happen to fried foods too i.e. do most of the fats and oil come out of the meat and get diluted in the cooking oil?  Thereafter only a small amount of the now diluted fat and oil is reabsorbed back into the meat or does the saturated fats and fish oils not come out during frying?

Comment: I assume that if you drop a fatty piece of meat in oil, some of the fat from the meat will melt away and mix in with the frying oil ?

Comment: Any fat will leave the meat with boiling, grilling or roasting?

Comment: @Paparazzi I'm not saying ALL fat since some will be remain but a lot comes out as you can see when you refrigerate and it becomes solid.

Comment: I am not real strong in English to me "any fat ... will leave" is "all fat".

Answer (score 1):

Chemically, yes. Heat turns solid fat to liquid form once it reaches its liquid phase temperature. That's why meat turns dry and chewy once oil dissolve (unless it gets cooked long enough the meat or protein chain decomposed into stew). People seared meat in high heat or breaded meat in deep fry in relatively short time to shield both the juice and marble fat from excessive dissolving and evaporation.

Comment: I think this answer may have misled the OP a bit. While *some* fat definitely is released, it's definitely nowhere close to *all* of it, and that also doesn't mean that cooking oil soaks into the meat to replace it.